# OP AMP fabrication technologies impacts on design

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am referring OP AMP selection guide for implementing it in medical application where it involves optical sensing using photo diode then I/V converter and ADC for data conversion.

My question is how OP AMP fabrication technology like BJT, FET, CMOS makes impact on design. I want to have more insight of fabrication aspects and its impacts (pros/cons) while implementing it in design.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually find a fabrication hint on the front page of a device's data sheet - it might say something like: -

> Single Supply, Rail-to-Rail, Low Power, FET-Input Op Amp

This is for the AD824 and it does mentions "FETs". However, I'd be more interested in it being low-power and rail-to-rail rather than the technology used.

But, "FET" input usually means low-bias currents so, do I then choose it on that basis? No, I certainly do not - I read the data sheet and look at the specified bias and offset currents and make a judgement on those numbers. In fact I don't give any credence to the word "FET" at all - I read the numbers and make a judgement on those numbers.

I did a search of "FET" in the document and a lot of mentions came up on page 1 (the BS page that should only be read with a pinch of salt) then, it wasn't until page 11 that the next mention of FET arose. One mention on page 12 and this time it said JFET - a more meaningful statement about technology but still, I'm not swayed because I read the numbers in the tables.

So, my advice from nearly 40 years of using op-amps on a regular basis is, forget the tech and read the data - understand the implications of each line in the tables of numbers because this is the true performance guarantee.

The other think is that if you go to TI's (or ADI's or LT's) website and do a search, it's a parametric search and not a fab/tech search. This should tell anyone to forget about fabrication methods and concentrate on real maximums and minimums and get reading the nitty-gritty of the data sheet.

However, if you don't know what you are aiming for as a design, spend more time thinking about this THEN start trawling the parametric tables and THEN compare data sheets.